# $a_n=\frac{(x/a_{n-1})+a_{n-1}}{2}$: Generalize to $n$th roots

Tags: calculus

> Let $x$ and $y$ be positive numbers. Let $a_0=y$, and let $$a_n=\frac{(x/a_{n-1})+a_{n-1}}{2}$$Prove that the sequence $\{a_n\}$ has limit $\sqrt{x}$. Generalize to $n$th roots.

I already solved the first part [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415125/limit-of-recursive-sequence-a-n-fracx-a-n-1a-n-12), but I have no idea how to generalize the $n$th roots. The limit should be $\sqrt[n]{x}$, but what is the recurrence supposed to look like?

Comment: You know how to find the limit for your given sequence, so why not use that method to get the new one? Replace the $a_i$'s in the equation that defines $\{a_n\}$ recursively with $\ell = \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$, and reverse engineer so that when you solve for $\ell$, you get $\sqrt[n]{x}$, then make sure that the sequence you just created converges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, following Stahl's hint in the comment, I think I got

$$a_n = \dfrac{x/a_{n-1}^{n-1}+(n-1)a_{n-1}}{n}.$$

Proof that it converges with limit $\sqrt[n]{x}$ is similar to the $n=2$ case.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) = x^n-a$. 
Newton's iteration for
$f(x) = 0$ is
$x = x-f(x)/f'(x)$.

Since $f'(x) = n x^{n-1}$,
the iteration is
$x = x - \frac{x^n-a}{n x^{n-1}}
= \frac{n x^n-(x^n-a)}{n x^{n-1}}
= \frac{(n-1) x^n+a}{n x^{n-1}}
= \frac{(n-1) x+a/x^{n-1}}{n}
$.

The general proof about Newton's
involves noting that
$f(x+h)
\approx f(x)+h f'(x) 
$.
To make this zero,
if $f(x) +h f'(x) = 0$,
$h = -f(x)/f'(x)$.

To make this rigorous,
you need bounds on $f''(x)$.
With that,
you can prove that if $x$
is close to a root,
the iteration converges.

There might be an explicit formula,
as there is for $n=2$,
but I don't feel like trying to work it out right now.